# Div that maintains aspect ratio, while filling it's container, which also maintains aspect ratio and fills screen

Tags: html, css, aspect-ratio

I am trying to create a setup where I have a container (see illustration below: blue) that maintains a 16:9 aspect ratio, and always fits on the screen (Is always as big as it can get while remaining entirely in the browser window).

And then it has a div inside of it (green) that also maintains a 16:9 aspect ratio and fills the outer container.

I need to be able to have another div (pink) above that one that contains a varying amount of text.

It would push down the green container, but the green container must maintain its 16:9 aspect ratio.

[image: illustration of my concept]

I have created a JSFiddle to show what I have tried so far, and how it is not yet working.

https://jsfiddle.net/paleosun/rky2bLhn/

My HTML:

```
<div class="outer-container">
  <!-- 
    This container should never be taller than the browser viewport...
    Actually, it should never be taller than the height of the viewport,
    minus the height of my sites header and footer.
    (My site has no vertical scrollbar)
    
    So, if the browser grows really wide, this container should
    stop growing, once the height gets maxxxed out.
  -->
 
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="header-text">
      This is the header text. It can be any number of lines. It is dynamic text. It can be short or tall. This is the header text. It can be any number of lines. It is dynamic text. It can be short or tall. This is the header text. It can be any number of lines. It is dynamic text. It can be short or tall.
    </div> <!-- /.header-text -->
    <div class="content-container">
      <div class="wrapper">  
        This should always be 16:9 and fill all available height in the inner-container.
      </div> <!-- /.wrapper -->
    </div> <!-- /.content-container -->
  </div> <!-- /.inner-container -->
</div> <!-- /.outer-container -->
```

MY CSS:

```
.outer-container{

  background-color: #d5e4f3;
  
    width: 100vw; 
    height: 56.25vw; /* 100/56.25 = 1.778 */
    max-height: calc(100vh - 200px); /* subtracting header and footer */
    max-width: calc(177.78vh - 355px); /* 16/9 = 1.778, = 355/200*/
    margin: 100px auto;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;bottom:0; /* vertical center */
    left:0;right:0; /* horizontal center */
  
  .inner-container{
    padding: 9px 16px;
  
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
  
    .header-text{
      background-color: #cab4d7;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    .content-container{
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #bad79d;
      
        max-height: 100%;
      
      >.wrapper{
        padding: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        bottom: 0px;        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In that example, I have the outer container doing what I want.

It maintains the 16:9 aspect ratio, and fills the available screen space, but stops growing once the height or width reaches the edge of the browser viewport.

I've got the inner container maintaining a 16:9 aspect ratio, but I can't figure out how to get it to stay within it's container as well.

Comment: `.outer-container` should have `position:relative` not `absolute`, try `fixed` since you plan to never exceed the viewport